# how to convert file path into file explore view in android

Tags: java, android

i my android i ve to buit an explorer view for files from cloud. I get the response as below string format.. can any one give an idea to show it in a file manager.

> "c:\myfolder\java\ss.class,c:\myfolder\java\javafolde\txet.txt,c:\first.doc 
>   "

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
    private String root="/";
    private List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if(!dirPath.equals(root)){
           item.add(root);
           path.add(root);
           item.add("../");
           path.add(f.getParent());
        }
```

Implement a [simple File Explorer in Android](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html)

Comment: The question is about building an explorer-like UI for files that are *not* actually on the device.  Getting lists of files on the device isn't relevant.

Comment: But the page you linked to has example layouts which *are* relevant.